# No sound ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, toshiba

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I have no sound. I do not know a lot about Ubuntu, but I have tried everything I could find on the Internet.

I did a 12 step solving plan from the Ubuntu site, but that didn't solve it.

I have a Toshiba S55Dt A5130 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
My laptop had Harman/Kardon boxes, idk if that is of any significance

Some more info:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`

00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller [1002:9902]
  Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller [1002:9902]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems FCH Azalia Controller [1179:fa95]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel


$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: 92HD99BXX Analog [92HD99BXX Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pactl list short sinks

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_01.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: tried my best, did as you said but no result. Would you like me to make screenshots of alsamixer and gnome-alsamixer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Praise the Lord!

I found an old article from 2013 of a person who had the same problem.
Eventually he succeeded by chaching the BIOS settings.

Disabling secure BOOT and changing EUFI to CDM BOOT.
Then I reinstalled Ubuntu. After that the sound worked!

Thanx again for the help and instructions.

Comment: "Disabling secure BOOT and changing EUFI to CDM BOOT" How did you do that? is this a setting somewhere in BIOS??

Comment: Yes, just go to in BIOS and search for it, I think it is in the boot options under the advanced button.

Answer (score 0):

Pls set volume using `alsamixer`command and select the appropriate device using `F6` key. Most of the user missed the default device selections[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x2Hb.png)

Comment: did so, but it did't work :/

Comment: Check .asoundrc file in ~/ folder, if exists delete it and play the music using aplay /use/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav file. If any error while playing audio using aplay  pls do post here.